# Facebook Log In Button always changing ID

Tags: selenium, facebook

I'm trying to automate my facebook log ins, but it seems like every time selenium runs a script and chrome window opens, the FB Log In buttons changes ID. I have the following statement written:

```
login_box = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_5_ni"]')
login_box.click()
```

For each new windows or refresh, the ID changes. How can I search or find the right path to be able to log in autocratically for each session?

Comment: I assume you are aware. Facebook doesn't allow you to programmatically interact with their website. So don't be surprised when you get banned.

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook login button has a "name" attribute and appears to be static, so you can use that locator to find it.

You appear to be using Python, your code will look like this:

```
login_box = wd.find_element_by_name('login')
login_box.click()
```

Still, if you want to use xpath then you can use text()

```
login_box = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Log in']")
login_box.click()
```

Comment: I'm trying to automate a listening in FB Marketplace so I don't have retype everything. In order to press on "Create new Listening" button, when I inspect the button I get this class:       class="x193iq5w xeuugli x13faqbe x1vvkbs x1xmvt09 x1lliihq x1s928wv xhkezso x1gmr53x x1cpjm7i x1fgarty x1943h6x xudqn12 x3x7a5m x6prxxf xvq8zen x1s688f x1mvi0mv". How do I write a command to click or find this particular class?